# COM Exception 0x800A11F9 - Cannot activate application

Tags: c#, com, interop, ms-word

I have a C# 2.0 (WinForms) project in which I try to activate word 2003 (word is installed on the system). By using the following code:

```
private void ActivateWord()
{
    this.Activate();

    if (m_WordDocument != null)
    {
        try
        {
            m_WordDocument.Activate();

            if (m_WordDocument.Application != null)
            {
                m_WordDocument.Application.Visible = true;
                m_WordDocument.Application.Activate();
            }
        }
        catch (COMException comEx)
        {
            ShowError(this, comEx.Message, false);
        }
    }
}
```

When my application executes m_WordDocument.Application.Activate() I receive a COM Exception 0x800A11F9.

```
Stacktrace:
    "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A11F9): Cannot activate application  
        at Word.ApplicationClass.Activate()  
        at Roxit.SquitXO.GUI.DocumentCreatie.frmSelectVeld.ActivateWord()"
```

What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: The error code googles well, just a few hits.  If that doesn't help you'll need Microsoft Support.

Comment: I'm seeing this exact same error, after spending a while futzing with DCOM config. I tried Googling, but no real luck (most sites are just copies of this SO question on other sites).

Answer (score 5):

COM error 0x800A11F9 is a [well-known](http://forums.asp.net/p/1214050/2147487.aspx) permission problem that occurs when an underprivileged user (such as `Network Service`) tries to activate an Office application.

In your case, the problem can't come from IIS since you're developing a WinForms application. Rather, it looks like your app is started by a Windows service running under the `Local Service` or `Network Service` user account.

If that's indeed the case, you need to change the user account used by the service in the `Log on` tab of the service's properties dialog box.

**EDIT:** You might want to try putting the code that activates Word into a [COM+ component](http://my.execpc.com/~gopalan/dotnet/complus/complus.net_accountmanager.html) and configuring the identity of the component so it runs under a user account that can launch Word.

Comment: In my case, this is being run from a web app. I can't change the user account because I'm using Sitecore, which requires a specific user to be logged on. I tried to give access via DCOM Config to the network service user, no dice. I then tried updating the global COM permissions for "Everyone" for "Launching and accessing", no dice.

Comment: Hmmmm, I've had similar problems in the past using MS word to generate documents on a web server. If I recall you need to give the service user rights and change the identity of the user running the application to a user with proper rights (DCom properties). That worked for me. Also you'll have tos set launch and activation permissions and other permissions in the security tag of DCom for Microsoft Word

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought i've seen a similar error when doing word automation on the server (which we no longer do due to flakiness), however at that time it was caused by permission issues from the ASP.net account, I know you are running in winforms but could this possibly be related to permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a permissions problem, and you can't get Sitecore to run as a user with sufficient permissions, perhaps you could write a different service ("WordService") for your Sitecore application to send requests to.  Then WordService could run as a slightly more privileged user, do your stuff with Word, then e.g. write the filled-in Word file to a known location SiteCore can access, or whatever you want it to do.