# Word interop: Visible always false

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, word-interop

I try to open word like following:

```
Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
app.Visible = true;
Console.WriteLine($"Visible {app.Visible}");
```

When running this code on my development machine (Windows 10, Office 365), Word appears (as expected) and output is:

> Visible: true

When running this code on the production machine (Windows Server 2019, Word 2019), Word **does not appear** and output is:

> Visible: false

There must be some issue on the production machine as everything went well until a week ago.

Windows event log doesn't show anything that points to this issue. Re-installing Word didn't help. When starting Word manually, it starts normal and appears as expected.

Does anybody know how to investigate further or what the cause of this issue could be?

**EDIT**
Whey I modify the code like this:

```
Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
app.Visible = true;
app.Activate(); // System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

... I get an Exception:

> Anwendung kann nicht aktiviert werden. HRESULT:0x800A11F9

I found the following article [COM Exception 0x800A11F9 - Cannot activate application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690180/com-exception-0x800a11f9-cannot-activate-application) but this doesn't provide a solution.
HRESULT:0x800A11F9

I run the application as administrator.

Comment: Try re-installing word on the production machine..

Comment: Re-installing word didn't help.

Comment: What happens when you try to start Word as an end-user on that machine?

Comment: Word starts normal and appears as expected. It is only invisible when using Interop.

Comment: Abid, remember to "ping" using the `@` symbol, otherwise no one will see that you've answered in comments. I was curious what the answer was, so only just saw your comment ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the issue.

Another application changed the Word security settings in *dcomcnfg*.

I changed the settings to the following (German / English):

- **General**: *Authentifizierungsebene: Keine* /
          *Authentication level: None*
- **Security**: choose Settings for all points and give all rights to *Administrators/Remotedesktop user* (the production server acts as
  terminal server)
- **Identity**: Option *Der Benutzer, der die Anwendung startet.* /
                  *The user who started the application.*

In *dcomcnfg*, Word isn't listed by name but by AppId. To find out, which AppId Word does have, I found this [article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/2012/11/12/microsoft-excel-or-microsoft-word-does-not-appear-in-dcom-configuration-snap-in/) which states

> Look for
>   **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{00020906-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}**